# Hydraulic steering goes left but not right

Tags: steering

I am working on a project with a group of friends. We have built a vehicle using a hydraulic orbital steering valve from an old ditch witch. The vehicle goes left but not right.

There are 5 ports on the valve. Every valve is plumbed the way it is labeled except one. Left and right are plumbed in. Aux,out, and an unlabeled port. The in port is plugged because it came off the ditch witch that way. The inlet is in the port labeled out and everything else except the inlet port plumbed the way it is labeled. The steer goes easy left but will not go right. What would cause the steering to go left but not right?

[image: orbital valve]

Comment: To clarify, you are using a hydraulic arm and pump for a ditchwitch and the pump only pumps one way?  If I'm incorrect, please clarify your question.  If I'm correct, please clarify your question.  Welcome to the site.  Cheers!

Comment: I clarified the question as best I could.

Comment: Have you completely bled the system of all air?  If so, how did you do it?

Comment: [Is this the part you are using?](http://www.vanderhaags.com/display.php?id=649252&width=490)

Comment: @paulster the part does look like the diagram.  We took the shaft off and attached it to a sprocket and drive motor.

Comment: @ducatikiller I will inquire with our hydraullics person later today.

Comment: You can get it to come back to straight after turning left?

Comment: If we push the tires it will straighten.

Comment: @paulster do you know what the port directly under the number 2 in the diagram is?

Comment: A picture of the actual valve you are working with would be nice.

Comment: @Moab - look at the link in my comment.